# Does Java optimize immutable objects?

Tags: java, optimization, immutability

Java strings are immutable, and instantiating multiple Strings with the same values returns the same object pointer. (Is there a term for this? "pooling" seems to fit, but that already refers to doing caching to save time by doing fewer instantiations.)

Does Java also do this (the thing without a term) with other (user-defined) classes that are immutable? Can Java even detect that a class is immutable, or is this something unique to the string class?

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I believe Java can recognize classes having only final members and treat them as immutable, but I have no precise information about that. I'll put an eye on this question. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't, and consider what would happen if you changed the immutable object anyway, with reflection..

Comment: I see, I'm a bit surprised about that. Thanks

Comment: *"Is there a term for this?"* Java calls it ["interning" the string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

Comment: `new String("blah") != new String("blah")` so your initial sentence isn't quite accurate.

Comment: @harold HotSpot does optimizations on `final` fields regardless of the fact that they can be mutated using reflection. They did consider what would happen and decided to do it anyway :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrt. Strings, the word you're looking for is [interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Java won't do this for your own immutable objects. It does have cached versions of boxed primitives, though. See this article on [wrapper class caching](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

As others here have said this process with Strings is known as interning.

Its worth mentioning that the behaviour of Strings with the same literal values being the same object may or may not be true in Java 7. From 7 onwards:

> In JDK 7, interned strings are no longer allocated in the permanent generation of the Java heap, but are instead allocated in the main part of the Java heap (known as the young and old generations), along with the other objects created by the application. This change will result in more data residing in the main Java heap, and less data in the permanent generation, and thus may require heap sizes to be adjusted. Most applications will see only relatively small differences in heap usage due to this change, but larger applications that load many classes or make heavy use of the String.intern() method will see more significant differences.

Take a look at [Java SE 7 RFE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#jdk7changes) for the full details on this.

With regards to your own immutable objects Java doesnt do anything special with them - it doesnt know that they're immutable.  It *may* inline methods a little more than otherwise if it can detect that its worthwhile/possible, but as far at the compiler and JVM are concerned they're just another object.

Comment: Wow, downvoted?  I can take a downvote, but would have been nice to know why

Answer (score 1):

The term you are lookig is itering. Java optimize strings "automatically", during compilation and give the developer possibility to do it on runtime. (The details about what is optimized when depend on JVM version.)

As far it goes for immutable objects. I do not think that Java support any type of mechanism that will resolve same instace. String type is not exeption of this rule.

Reason why, is that you have to use operator `new` to create a instance. If you use `new` to create string instance, you will always get two different objects.

The intering is avaiable only for String type. But the concept is free, you can add to your immutable class such method and write an compled method that will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

String **interning**. Wikipedia: [String Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)

Answer (score 0):

String Interning is unique to String class only. I suppose that JVM does not apply these rules for a user defined classes.